# Printing a list of lists C++ STL list

Tags: c++, list, stl, cout

I have a top list that stores inner lists. I'm using the standard template library list template.

I am attempting to print the values of the inner lists.
The top list is "L" and the inner list is "I".

```
void ListofLists::dump()
{
    list<list<IntObj>>::iterator itr;
    for (itr = L.begin(); itr != L.end(); itr++)
    {
        list<IntObj>::iterator it;
        for (it = I.begin(); it != I.end(); it++)
        {
            cout << *it << "  ";
        } 
        cout << endl << "End" << endl;
    }
}
```

My IDE doesn't like the line  `cout << *it << "  ";`and I'm not really sure how to change it while having the program do what I want it to do, which is print the data inside of the lists.
It red underlined the “<<“ operator and says “no operator “<<“ matches these operands.”

Can someone help me as to why? I've looked and can't really find what I'm looking for. I'm not understanding something correctly. I know it is adding the data to the data structure correctly because my IDE enables me to view my locals.

Thanks to anyone who helps! Means a lot.

Comment: It's trying to print an `IntObj` have you added to the code to do this?

Comment: You say that you have a list that stores lists, but that is not what you have. You have two unrelated lists, that you try to output using a nested loop for some reason. Also, please clarify "My IDE doesn't like" and create a [mcve] thanks.

Comment: I don't like spinach, your IDE doesn't like your line of code. That's how we all have our quirks.

Comment: Did you implement `<<` for `IntObj`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
list<IntObj>::const_iterator i;
```

instead the one you are using to avoid compiling error.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop does not make sense.

If you want to use iterators then the function can be defined like

```
void ListofLists::dump() /* const */
{
    for (list<list<IntObj>>::iterator itr = L.begin(); itr != L.end(); itr++)
    {
        for ( list<IntObj>::iterator it = itr->begin(); it != itr->end(); it++)
        {
            cout << *it << "  ";
        } 
        cout << endl << "End" << endl;
    }
}
```

However it will be simpler to use the range-based for loop. For example

```
void ListofLists::dump() /* const */
{
    for ( const auto &inner_list : L )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : inner_list )
        {
            cout << item << "  ";
        } 
        cout << endl << "End" << endl;
    }
}
```

Take into account that you have to define the `operator <<` for the class `IntObj`.
Its declaration should look like

```
std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &, const IntObj & );
```

Comment: Can i define the ostream operator for IntObj outside of the IntObj class? I'm unable to edit the IntObj files. Thanks vlad.

Comment: @AliciaSabatino You can define it inside the class, In this case the ADL look-up will be used. If the operator accesses directly private data members of the class then the operator has to be declared as friend.

Comment: Okay. so say the value is stored in m_data in the IntObj... would I just write cout << m_data in the overloaded function?

Comment: @AliciaSabatino You can provided that the operator << is defined also for m_data and the function has access to this data member..

Comment: Is there a way to do it with out defining it for m_data?

Comment: @AliciaSabatino No there is not. That is you can not write os << obj.m_data without defining its operator by you or by C++ itself.